# How to send a video via XMLhttprequest and as multipart/form body content? Video not sent?

Tags: javascript, node.js, azure, xmlhttprequest, azure-cognitive-services

I have a webpage I am trying to allow a video to be sent to my API via XMLhttprequest as below:

```
   <form onsubmit="submitBtn()"> 
   <input type="file" accept="video/*" name="fileupload" value="fileupload" id="fileupload"> 
   <label for="fileupload"> Select a file to upload
   </label> 
   <input type="submit" value="submit">
   </form>

<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
  function submitBtn() {
    var search = document.getElementById('fileupload').value;
    if (search.length>0){
        var text = search;
userAction(text);
    } 
  }
</script>

<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
  function userAction(res) {
      var formData = new FormData();
      formData.append("video", res);
    var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
    var api = 'myApi'
    request.open('POST', api, true);
    request.onload = function () {
      // Begin accessing JSON data here
      var data = this.response;
      if (request.status >= 200 && request.status < 400) {
           console.log('celebrate');
      } else {
        console.log('error');
      }
    }
    request.send(formData);
}

</script>
```

This part seems to work fine, however, I don't believe the video itself is sent to my API. If I `context.log(result.body)` I get something similar to:

```
------WebKitFormBoundary1234
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="video"

C:\fakepath\videoname.mp4
------WebKitFormBoundaryq1234--
```

I wish to then send this video to another API as multipart/form body content.

I have attempted this by using:

```
function videoAPI (context, auth, vid, callback){
    var body = vid;

    var requestUrl = urlApi;
    const requestOptions = {
        hostname: requestUrl.hostname,
        path: requestUrl.path,
        method: 'POST',
        headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data',
        }
    };

    var request = https.request(requestOptions, function(res) {
        var data = "";
        res.on('data', function (chunk) {
            context.log('Response: ' + chunk);
            data += chunk;
        });
        res.on('end', function () {
            var jsonData = JSON.parse(data);
callback(jsonData);         

        });        
    })
    request.write(body);
    request.end();    
}
```

Again, this functions, however, the response I get is:

```
Input is invalid. Input must specify either a video url, an asset id or provide a multipart content body
```

This seems to suggest that I am either not sending the video correctly, or I am not sending it correctly via the XMLhttprequest.

Can someone highlight where I have gone wrong and how to correct it please?

I am using nodejs and Azure.

Comment: invalid syntax: `<input type="submit" value="</form>`

Comment: form attributes should be lowercase. `<form onSubmit=` -> `<form onsubmit=`

Comment: @Endless apologies, the invalid syntax was an error in copying my code, I have adjusted the form attribute (though this didn't seem to affect it), the same issues remain. I have edited accordingly, thanks.

Comment: @Endless — HTML attribute names are case-insensitive.